# Create database index with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using **SequelizeJS** v1.7.6 and i need in model somehow define indexes on fields, i don't need compositing indexes so nothing complicated. What i found is option where you can only set up if the field should have unique index.

```
id:
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED
  index: yes # something like that does not work
```

But could not find way how can i set up classic index by some attribute or manually.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Not currently supported, see https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1485 for progress and workarounds

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it is not possible in the 1.7.* version -- but will be in Sequelize version 2.0 via this [pull-request comment](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/2057).

Also you can use the [`addIndex`](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/1.7.8/migrations#block-13-line-0) Sequelize Migrations command to create indexes outside of the model definition.